# What is the probability of getting the Unicorn Horn and Amulet in Castle Keep?

Tags: candy-box

I've gone through the Castle Keep like 5 times and still have no Unicorn Horn or Amulet.

How can I go about getting the Unicorn Horn and Amulet? What is the probability of getting the Unicorn Horn and Amulet in Castle Keep?

Comment: It's completely random.  You get the horn from a unicorn, and the amulet from a...wall troll?  I think?

Comment: Thanks for the answer. But is there a reason why this question has a negative 1 on it? I mean, cmon. It's a completely legit question...

Comment: As @fbueckert said, it's completely random.

Comment: @Cat I edited in "What is the probability of getting the Unicorn Horn and Amulet" into your question and changed the title, so the question can be more answerable (get a better explanation than "it's completely random"). If you do not like this, just roll back a previous edit or edit the question again.

Answer (score 2):

The magical horn and old amulet are guaranteed drops from the wall zombie and the unicorn lacking a kidney (`WZW`, `UNI`). Things is, you don't get these enemies each run.

Each time you start the quest, 4 of the rooms you visit are randomly generated from a set of 8 different rooms. The probability of getting at least 1 of a specific room is therefore:

```
1 - (7 / 8)^4 ≈ 41%
```

TL;DR The probability for the horn and amulet is the same (**41%**) since they both occur only in one specific random room. You've just been unlucky, keep trying.